# Should we create a [rasa-nlu] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I believe we should create a tag for Rasa NLU.

[Project homepage](https://rasa.ai).

See these questions:

- [Rasa Nlu testing: TypeError: object pickle not returning list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073276/rasa-nlu-testing-typeerror-object-pickle-not-returning-list)
- [No module named pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548300/no-module-named-pipeline)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761201/when-i-do-heroku-open-on-my-cli-i-want-it-to-open-a-module-in-this-case-a-v

It's quite [an active project on gitter](https://gitter.im/golastmile/rasa_nlu) and [GitHub](http://github.com/golastmile/rasa_nlu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and created [rasa-nlu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rasa-nlu) and added it to those three questions.  It does not have a tag wiki or excerpt so feel free to write one if you want.